# Minimal self-contained mathematical description of classical relativistic mechanics

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, classical-mechanics

I am not a physicist and I'm looking to know the equations of motion of a collection of particles with electromagnetic forces, under special relativity. That is, if we have a collection of particles with an electromagnetic force between them and possibly an external force, what would the equations of motion for such a system be assuming special relativistic but not quantum dynamics. **Could you tell me the name for such equations of motion, so I can search for it?**

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you properly, these are just Maxwell's equations.  You probably want them in manifestly relativistic form.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity

You can add to that the the dynamics of your point particles using standard Lagrangian techniques.  Here's a related example of that for a single particle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Lagrangian_mechanics#Special_relativistic_test_particle_in_an_electromagnetic_field

Comment: It's worth noting as well that just coupling in this way leads to divergences for point particles which requires a (I believe mass) renormalization, even classically.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand, but aren't maxwell's equations a description of fields rather than point particles? Having read a bit, maybe what I need is the relativistic version of coulomb's law?

Comment: You get the fields and then you can compute the force using the Lorentz force law: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Relativistic_form_of_the_Lorentz_force